# Generating Doctrine 2 entities with multiple database connections in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, doctrine-orm, oci8

For a web application, I have to work with 3 seperate databases:

- MySQL for all the application logic, such as login
- MSSQL Server for inserting records
- Oracle server for inserting records

Now i have read a lot of tutorials and manuals to configure those databases, so it now looks like this:

**doctrine.global.php**

```
return array(
'doctrine' => array(
    'connection' => array(
        'orm_default' => array(
            'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver',
            'params' => array(
                'host' => '123.123.123.123',
                'port' => '3306',
                'dbname' => 'db_name',
            ),
        ),
              'orm_oracle' => array(
                  'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\OCI8\Driver',
                  'params' => array(
                      'host' => '321.321.321.321', 
                      'port' => '1521',
                      'dbname' => 'something',
                      'driver' => 'oci8',
                      'servicename' => 'something', 
                  ),
              ),
              'orm_microsoft' => array(
                  'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\SQLSrv\Driver',
                  'params' => array(
                      'host' => '231.231.231.231', 
                      'port' => '1433',
                      'dbname' => 'something',
                      'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
                  ),
              ),
     )
)
);
```

**doctrine.local.php***

```
return array(
'doctrine' => array(
    'connection' => array(
        'orm_default' => array(
            'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver',
            'params' => array(
                'user' => 'brportal',
                'password' => '27607097b4',
                ),
            ),
        //Alternative DB connection
        'orm_oracle' => array(
            'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\OCI8\Driver',
            'params' => array(
                'user' => 'joost',
                'password' => '4b58tL8DFv7G',
            ),
        ),  
        'orm_microsoft' => array(
            'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\SQLSrv\Driver',
            'params' => array(
                'user' => 'joost',
                'password' => '4b58tL8DFv7G',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'entitymanager' => array(
        'orm_default' => array(
            'connection'    => 'orm_default',
            'configuration' => 'orm_default',
        ),
        'orm_oracle' => array(
            'connection'    => 'orm_oracle',
            'configuration' => 'orm_oracle',
        ),
        'orm_microsoft' => array(
            'connection'    => 'orm_microsoft',
            'configuration' => 'orm_microsoft',
        ),
    ),

    // Use array cache locally, also auto generate proxies on development environment.
    'configuration' => array(
        'orm_default' => array(
            'metadata_cache' => 'array',
            'query_cache' => 'array',
            'result_cache' => 'array',
            'hydration_cache' => 'array',
            'generate_proxies' => true,
        ),
        'orm_oracle' => array(
            'metadata_cache' => 'array',
            'query_cache' => 'array',
            'result_cache' => 'array',
            'hydration_cache' => 'array',
            'generate_proxies' => true,
        ),
        'orm_microsoft' => array(
            'metadata_cache' => 'array',
            'query_cache' => 'array',
            'result_cache' => 'array',
            'hydration_cache' => 'array',
            'generate_proxies' => true,
        ),
    ),
)
);
```

**Module.php**

```
'doctrine' => array(
'driver' => array(
    __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver' => array(
        'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
        'cache' => 'array',
        'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '\..\src\\' . __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entities')
        ),
    'orm_default' => array(
        'drivers' => array(
            __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entities' => __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver'
            )
        ),
    'oracle_driver' => array(
        'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
        'cache' => 'array',
        'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '\..\src\\' . __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entities\Oracle')
        ),
    'orm_oracle' => array(
        'drivers' => array(
            __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entities\Oracle' => 'oracle_driver'
            )
        ),
    'microsoft_driver' => array(
        'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
        'cache' => 'array',
        'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '\..\src\\' . __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entities\Microsoft')
        ),
    'orm_microsoft' => array(
        'drivers' => array(
            __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entities\Microsoft' => 'microsoft_driver'
            )
        )
    )
)
```

But now, i would really like to have a easy way to (re)generate the mssql and oracle database entities (annotations). It already worked with the MySQL database, but i can't find out how to specify a database connection with `doctrine-module orm:convert-mapping`.

I was wondering if anyone can help me with this?

Thanks in advance guys!

ps: I already read : 
[Zend Framework 2 and Doctrine 2 - Configuration for multiple databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24042353/zend-framework-2-and-doctrine-2-configuration-for-multiple-databases)

Comment: Have you tried: doctrine-module orm:convert-mapping --connection=orm_oracle?

Comment: No I didn't try that, however, i didn't see it listed as a option either. But i will try, thanks for the reply

Comment: Unfortunately, it reacted as supected:
    
  [RuntimeException]
  The "--connection" option does not exist.

Comment: So your Oracle and Microsoft Entities are subfolders of your MySql entities?

Answer (score 0):

The bottom line is that it is not supported in the ZF2 DoctrineORM module. There is a [feature request for it on the repo](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule/issues/97).

In the meantime there is a module that provides a shim module that add the --em option
https://github.com/SwissEngine/Doctrine-Module-Extension

Comment: Does in the meantime there is another solution?

Comment: I suggested that, until the feature is added to DoctrineORM, you can use the Doctrine-Module-Extension to get some of the functionality