# Change database connection dynamically in doctrine/DoctrineMongoODMModule

Tags: php, mongodb, zend-framework2, doctrine-odm

I want to connect with multiple databases on different servers in `zf2` using `doctrine`/`DoctrineMongoODMModule`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I hope this will help , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003187/configure-multiple-databases-in-zf2

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15277277/connect-to-multiple-data-bases-using-zend-framework-2-and-doctrineormmodule

Comment: solution not working :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use standard flow for one connection.. 
For second connection you can create it by factory into the service manager..
Into the [second part of this chapter](http://doctrine-mongodb-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html#persistent-models) you can see how create connection..